# Weibull, Gumbell and Extreme Value: from mean and variance to shape, scale and location parameter

Tags: variance, mean, weibull-distribution, extreme-value, gumbel-distribution

I need to sample random numbers from Weibull, Gumbel and Generalized extreme value distributions. Of all of these distributions I know mean and variance. My question is: how can I determine these parameters? Is there any analytical way, or approximation (concerning the approximations, I already found [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159452/how-can-i-recreate-a-weibull-distribution-given-mean-and-standard-deviation-and) for Weibull, but it is an approximation valid for wind, that is not my case)? Otherwise, how could I do it via an iterative method?

Comment: You can look for the method of moments